# Evaluating $\iint_D \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}\, dxdy$ using polar coordinates

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

I need to evaluate

$$\iint_D \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}\, dxdy$$

where $D: x\le x^2 + y^2\le 1$.

I can change this using polar coordinates. That is,

$$\iint_D r\cdot r\,drd\theta$$

where $0\le r\le 1$. But I cannot guess the range of $\theta$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint. The inequality $x^2 + y^2\leq 1$ represents the disc centred at $(0,0)$ and radius $1$.

On the other hand, the inequality $ x\leq x^2 + y^2$, which is equivalent to $(x-1/2)^2+y^2\geq 1/4$, is the complement of the disc centred at $(1/2,0)$ and radius $1/2$.

Now make a drawing of $D$.